# I am always getting null in the **transferReceivedData** object in Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have checked on Google and wasn't able to figure out the issue and also I am new to Spring and JSON.

Following is the code for the JS and JSON:

```
function SubmitData() {

    var transferReceivedData = {};
    var completeList = {};

    var totalnumberRecords = document.getElementById('numberOfRecords').value;

    for (j = 1; j <= totalnumberRecords; j++) {

        var transferIdMain = document.getElementById('transferIdHidden' + j).value;
        var subDetailsRowCount = $('#subTable' + j + ' tr').length; 

        var subRowsData = {};

        if (subDetailsRowCount != 1 && subDetailsRowCount != 0) {

            subDetailsRowCount = subDetailsRowCount - 1;

            for (i = 0; i < subDetailsRowCount; i++) {

                var articledesc = document
                        .getElementById('articleDescHidden' + transferIdMain).value;
                var shpQty = document.getElementById('shpQtyHidden'
                        + transferIdMain).value;
                var remarks = document.getElementById('remarks'
                        + transferIdMain).value;
                var transferId = document.getElementById('transferId'
                        + transferIdMain).value;

                subRowsData = {transferId:transferId,
                        articleDesc:articledesc,
                        shpQty:shpQty,
                        remarks:remarks};
            }
        }

        completeList = {
            transferId:transferIdMain,
            childList:subRowsData
        };

        transferReceivedData = {
            completeList : completeList
        };
    }

     var requestLength = transferReceivedData.length;

     console.log("completeList", completeList);

     console.log("transferReceivedData", transferReceivedData);      

     alert("requestLength.... "+requestLength);      

     if (requestLength != 0) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Pda/saveGoods",
             data: JSON.stringify(transferReceivedData),
             success: function (response) {                  
             }
         });
     }
}
```

---

Following is the code of Spring controller :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = {
        "/saveGoods" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String saveGoods(ModelMap model, HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute PDATransferDataAll transferReceivedData) {

    Employee user = (Employee) session.getAttribute("currentUser");

    int res = 0;

    if (transferReceivedData != null) {

        res = 0; //pdaService.saveGoods(completeList, user);
    }
    if (res != 0) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Data saved successfully.");
        model.addAttribute("id", res);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Data Not saved ");
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Following are the beans :-

```
public class PDATransferDataAll implements Serializable {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private PDATransferData completeList;

    /**
    * 
    */
    public PDATransferDataAll() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
    * @return the completeList
    */
    public PDATransferData getCompleteList() {
        return completeList;
    }

    /**
    * @param completeList
    *            the completeList to set
    */
    public void setCompleteList(PDATransferData completeList) {
        this.completeList = completeList;
    }
```

---

```
public class PDATransferData implements Serializable {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String transferId;

    private List<PDATransferReceivedPojo> childList;

    /**
    * @return the transferId
    */
    public String getTransferId() {
        return transferId;
    }

    /**
    * @param transferId
    *            the transferId to set
    */
    public void setTransferId(String transferId) {
        this.transferId = transferId;
    }

    /**
    * @return the childList
    */
    public List<PDATransferReceivedPojo> getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }

    /**
    * @param childList
    *            the childList to set
    */
    public void setChildList(List<PDATransferReceivedPojo> childList) {
        this.childList = childList;
    }
```

---

```
public class PDATransferReceivedPojo implements Serializable {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String transferId;
    private String articleDesc;
    private String articleTechDesc;
    private String shpQty;
    private String receivedQty;
    private String status;
    private String orderType;
    private String remarks;

    /**
    * @return the transferId
    */
    public String getTransferId() {
        return transferId;
    }

    /**
    * @param transferId
    *            the transferId to set
    */
    public void setTransferId(String transferId) {
        this.transferId = transferId;
    }

    /**
    * @return the articleDesc
    */
    public String getArticleDesc() {
        return articleDesc;
    }

    /**
    * @param articleDesc
    *            the articleDesc to set
    */
    public void setArticleDesc(String articleDesc) {
        this.articleDesc = articleDesc;
    }

    /**
    * @return the shpQty
    */
    public String getShpQty() {
        return shpQty;
    }

    /**
    * @param shpQty
    *            the shpQty to set
    */
    public void setShpQty(String shpQty) {
        this.shpQty = shpQty;
    }

    /**
    * @return the receivedQty
    */
    public String getReceivedQty() {
        return receivedQty;
    }

    /**
    * @param receivedQty
    *            the receivedQty to set
    */
    public void setReceivedQty(String receivedQty) {
        this.receivedQty = receivedQty;
    }

    /**
    * @return the status
    */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
    * @param status
    *            the status to set
    */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
    * @return the orderType
    */
    public String getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    /**
    * @param orderType
    *            the orderType to set
    */
    public void setOrderType(String orderType) {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    /**
    * @return the remarks
    */
    public String getRemarks() {
        if (remarks == null || remarks.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            remarks = "";
        }
        return remarks;
    }

    /**
    * @param remarks
    *            the remarks to set
    */
    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        if (remarks == null || remarks.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            remarks = "";
        }
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    /**
    * @return the articleTechDesc
    */
    public String getArticleTechDesc() {
        return articleTechDesc;
    }

    /**
    * @param articleTechDesc
    *            the articleTechDesc to set
    */
    public void setArticleTechDesc(String articleTechDesc) {
        this.articleTechDesc = articleTechDesc;
    }
```

Comment: If anyone has any doubt then please let me know.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I wonder if readers could do with seeing what debugging you have done. I take it the issue is in the Spring controller?